# Ordered write to the same file with ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, reentrantlock

I'm trying to instantiate tasks in a ExecutorService that need to write to file in order,so if there exist 33 tasks they need to write in order...

I've tried to use LinkedBlockingQueue and ReentrantLock to guarantee the order but by what I'm understanding in fair mode it unlock to the youngest of the x threads  ExecutorService have created.

```java
private final static Integer cores =      Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(false);
private final ExecutorService taskExecutor;
```

In constructor

```java
taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor
        (cores, cores, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
```

and so I process a quota of a input file peer task

```java
if(s.isConverting()){
   if(fileLineNumber%quote > 0) tasks = (fileLineNumber/quote)+1;
   else tasks = (fileLineNumber/quote);
   for(int i = 0 ; i<tasks || i<1 ; i++){
      taskExecutor.execute(new ConversorProcessor(lock,this,i));
   }
}
```

the task do

```java
public void run() {
    getFileQuote();
    resetAccumulators();
    process();
    writeResult();
}
```

and my problem ocurre here:

```java
private void writeResult() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/conversion.txt",true));
        Integer index = -1;
        if(i == 0){
            bw.write("ano dia tmin tmax tmed umid vento_vel rad prec\n");
        }
        while(index++ < getResult().size()-1){
            bw.write(getResult().get(index) + "\n");
        }
        if(i == controller.getTasksNumber()){ 
            bw.write(getResult().get(getResult().size()-1));
        }
        else{ 
            bw.write(getResult().get(getResult().size()-1) + "\n");
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConversorProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally { 
        lock.unlock(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need to write things in order, why do you need multiple threads? Why not use a single threaded executor?

Comment: @vanza: because he still needs concurrency with most of his code except the write to file code.

Comment: That's a much longer discussion though. Disk is generally much slower, so unless he's doing a whole lot of computation, multiple threads won't help (Amdahl etc etc). He can still use a separate, single threaded executor just for the I/O part if he really wants to.

Comment: (Oh, and if his concurrent tasks are actually accessing the disk during the computation, they'll probably hurt more than help due to seeks.)

Comment: @vanza all data is obtained in getFileQuote, each thread get a bunch of sequencial lines from the archive and work with it, so for 33 tasks the file is readed 33 times to get a sequential part of it. anyway I can't work in all scenarios with the complete file, I'm interested in being able of converting files on GB size in systems with not so abundant RAM.

Comment: As counter intuitive as it may seem, if your file is on a single disk and your computation is trivial compared to the I/O costs, your code will probably perform better single-threaded. But if you really want to use multiple threads, use Hovercraft's solution, or write to multiple output files and build the final result in a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that everything needs to be done concurrently ***except*** the writing of the output to file, and this must be done in the object creation order.

I would take the code that writes to the file, the `writeResult()` method, out of your threading code, and instead create Futures that returned Strings that are created by the `process()` method, and load the Futures into an `ArrayList<Future<String>>`. You then could iterate through the ArrayList, in a for loop calling `get()` on each Future, and writing the result to your text file with your BufferedWriter or PrintWriter.

Comment: but this would increase memory footprint, writing directly from the thread did not maintain all result in memory

Comment: If you don't want to maintain all results in memory, you're gonna have to spill them to disk (in separate files) and then assemble the final file from the intermediate ones in the order you need.

Comment: @user2884025: No, it would not increase the memory foot print at all. Even if it were written to file in thread, since you have to write all the data in order, you'd still have to hold the data in memory while awaiting the completion of writing from the threads that were started earlier.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Correct-me if Im wrong, but writing in threads I will only have thread result memory parcels, otherwise I will need all tasks memory... In my scenario I have only 4 threads in my machine and it can passe from 30 tasks.

Comment: I used @HovercraftFullOfEels idea of using Futures so I could write inside threads,but using Futures to lock next thread so it wait to write in correct time I will further analyze alternatives if needed but in the moment the answer solved my problem. Thanks!